# Check multiple conditions given the set of items in each row and assign a value under new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
ex_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'Item': {0: {1}, 1: {1, 2}, 2: {1, 3, 4}, 3: {1, 3}}})
```

- Package 1 is when there is only item 1
- Package 2 is when there are items 1, 2
- Package 3 is when there are items 1, 3, 4
- Package 4 is when there are items 1, 3

I am trying to find a way to identify the type of a package given the set of items in each row.

so the result df should be:

```
ex_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'Item': {0: {1}, 1: {1, 2}, 2: {1, 3, 4}, 3: {1, 3}}, 'Package': {0: 'Package1', 1: 'Package2', 2: 'Package3', 3: 'Package4'}})
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#frozenset) to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values:

```
d = {frozenset({1}): 'Package1',
     frozenset({1, 2}): 'Package2',
     frozenset({1, 3, 4}): 'Package3',
     frozenset({1, 3}): 'Package4'}

ex_df['Package'] = ex_df['Item'].apply(frozenset).map(d)
```

output:

```
   ID       Item   Package
0   1        {1}  Package1
1   2     {1, 2}  Package2
2   3  {1, 3, 4}  Package3
3   4     {1, 3}  Package4
```

##### alternative: largest subset if no match:

```
ex_df['Package'] = ex_df['Item'].apply(frozenset).map(d)

m = ex_df['Package'].isna()

sets = sorted(d, key=lambda x: -len(x))

ex_df.loc[m, 'Package'] = [d.get(next((s for s in sets if x.issuperset(s)), None))
                           for x in ex_df.loc[m, 'Item']]
```

Example:

```
   ID       Item   Package
0   1        {1}  Package1
1   2     {1, 2}  Package2
2   3  {1, 3, 4}  Package3
3   4     {1, 3}  Package4
4   5  {1, 5, 6}  Package1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments.
What if in the data, the item could contain other irrelevant items?
For ex, ID 1, it could contain item {1, 5, 6} but we still want to identify it as Package 1

Comment: Then you would need unfortunately to loop over the items and test if the set is a superset of any of the targets (starting with largests)

Comment: I would much appreciate if you can share some of the codes to start the loop